# Salesforce forecast - for integration of Forecasts from SFDC

Tags: support

We have full sandbox environment.We are integrating information from SQL SERVER-SFDC.Then, We need to Perform Forecast on it.

**We have identified 2 options :**

**case 1:** We have to write apex code on SFDC that will send an outbound response message to a URL

or

**case 2:** WE have to  create a polling service that will query SFDC or an object, object will be used to run the integration now. Once polling service sees the integration it hasn’t seen before then it will run

**Problem:** Which Option is best suited and why?  which one easier to implement because i got confused about those cases. and if there any other way we can implement which is alternative of both the options.

Any help on it would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing forecasting, I'm going to guess that you're doing something related to Opportunity or one of its children. As you don't say what the volume of records is, it's difficult to properly advise you. You do have a number of options though. One of the documents I recommend you look at that you'll find helpful is [Integration Patterns and Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/).

If you're trying to follow records as they're created and updated, using outbound messaging through workflow would likely be your most optimal solution. That's the `Remote Process Invocation—Fire and Forget` pattern.

If your need for timely updates isn't particularly high, you may also want to consider creating a batch class that runs on a scheduled basis to queries your records, then make outbound web services calls to your endpoint to send updates. That's the `Batch Data Synchronization` pattern.

There are other options as well which the document clearly explains. You'll find all the documentation on the various APIs that Salesforce supports at [Developer Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/).

Comment: Can we use Asynchronous  apex call  instead of Outbound messaging.? Because Queuing along with Real time updates is our concern.We are only using Upsert action for our jobs. also record volumes are 2 GB in full sandbox environment. and we are doing for real time updates   for order and its line item.

Comment: To use Asynchronous apex you would need to have a method of triggering the Asynch calls. That would typically involve triggers that fire when the upsert happens, making an @future call to either a batchable class or a queueable class (preferred). Outbound messaging is much more robust and won't eat up your API call limits like triggers and asynch methods will.  But yes, it's certainly possible. You'd also want to implement record tracking/error handling to make certain you didn't lose any records if the future call failed for some reason.